# MySQL: REGEXP to remove part of a record

Tags: mysql, regex

I have a table "locales" with a column named "name". The records in name always begin with a number of characters folowed by an underscore (ie "foo_", "bar_"...). The record can have more then one underscore and the pattern before the underscore may be repeated (ie "foo_bar_", "foo_foo_").

How, with a simple query, can I get rid of everything before the first underscore including the first underscore itself?
I know how to do this in PHP, but I cannot understand how to do it in MySQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SELECT LOCATE('_', 'foo_bar_') ...` will give you the location of the first underscore and `SUBSTR('foo_bar_', LOCATE('_', 'foo_bar_'))` will give you the substring starting from the first underscore. If you want to get rid of that one, too, increment the locate-value by one.

If you now want to replace the values in the tables itself, you can do this with an update-statement like `UPDATE table SET column = SUBSTR(column, LOCATE('_', column))`.

Answer (score 0):

```
select substring('foo_bar_text' from locate('_','foo_bar_text'))
```

Answer (score -1):

MySQL REGEXs can only match data, they can't do replacements. You'd need to do the replacing client-side in your PHP script, or use standard string operations in MySQL to do the changes.

```
UPDATE sometable SET somefield=RIGHT(LENGTH(somefield) - LOCATE('_', somefield));
```

Probably got some off-by-one errors in there, but that's the basic way of going about it.